# How to reform array

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, dataset, tensorflow

After executing this code: https://www.kaggle.com/naveenc131/cnn-with-accuracy-of-98/code, an error occurred:

ValueError: error while checking input: it is expected that conv2d_1_input has 4 dimensions, but got an array with the form (0, 1)

(Dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/moltean/fruits)

**What** is the cause of the error, and **how** to fix the code?